# Transformation by right vector using TransformPoint return an identical position

Tags: transformation, unity

I think the following code should work. I'm trying to set the position of a GameObject where the pointer currently is, I mean, where the player is looking currently:

```
public void SetTransform (Transform callerTransform) {
   Debug.Log("original position: " + transform.position);
   Debug.Log("caller GameObject position: " + callerTransform.position);
   transform.position = callerTransform.TransformPoint(Vector3.right);
   Debug.Log("result position: " + transform.position);
}
```

Unfortunately it seems that TransformPoint is doing absolutely nothing as we can see on the logs. Vector3.right has been not change the position:

- original position: (0.0, 1.2, 1.0)
- caller GameObject position: (0.0, 1.0, 0.2)
- result position: (0.0, 1.0, 0.2)

I also have tried the following code with the same result:

```
GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = callerTransform.TransformPoint(Vector3.right);
```

But it seems senseless for me (callerTransform is not a RectTransform, gameObject.transform is a canvas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unity doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) says about `Transform.TransformPoint`:

> [...]Note that the returned position is affected by scale. [...]

And [from the same doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-right.html), `Vector3.right` is just a:

> Shorthand for writing Vector3(1, 0, 0).

So `callerTransform.TransformPoint(Vector3.right);` does nothing because a transformation with a right vector would only affect the x-axis, but as long as it is affected by scale, it does nothing when your initial x value is 0, which is your case.

I suggest to try what the [method doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) suggests:

> [...]Use Transform.TransformDirection if you are dealing with direction vectors.[...]

For example, the following code is working:

```
// The new position will be nine times to the right of callerTransform. 
Vector3 vectorPointingToTheRightOfCallerTransformInTheWorldSpace = callerTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
callerTransform.position = callerTransform.position + (vectorPointingToTheRightOfCallerTransformInTheWorldSpace * 9);
```

Comment: I have found and explanation of the diferences between [TransformPoint and TransformDirection here](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/154181/view.html). I have changed my code to `transform.position = callerTransform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0f,0f,1f));` as I want the position on the front of the callerTranform GameObject. The result position is now different, but it is not located where I want. There is something I don't understand yet. Thank you for your answer before I forget!

Comment: I'm sure if it is working or not yet, so I think I shouldn't accept this answer as the correct one to avoid confusions to people who find this issue later.

Comment: I have added a working sample to your answer. Sorry for the delay and thanks for your answer one more time! :)